# Vagrant Complaining about missing VMWare License

Tags: vagrant

So first of all I do not want to use VMWare with Vagrant. I want to use VirtualBox. I am running on OSX 10.9 by the way.

A few days ago I installed Vagrant. I followed the instructions to set up VMWare Fusion and added the provider.

```
--provider=vmware_fusion
```

I then realised you had to pay for another license to use VMWare Fusion with Vagrant. I opted out of that. So I downloaded VirtualBox and installed it. I removed VMWare Fusion completely. Removed Vagrant following the instructions on the page, and also ran Onyx to clean up anything. I ran a 'find' command and there was no Vagrant files on the system.

I reinstalled Vagrant. Reinstalled VirtualBox. When I ran:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

I got the following error:

```
A valid license is required to run the Vagrant VMware
provider. Please visit http://www.vagrantup.com to purchase
a license. Once you purchase a license, you can install it
using `vagrant plugin license`.
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.

exit
```

Any Vagrant command I run outputs this error.

I've been struggling to get this working for days. I have no VMWare files on my system, and I removed all of the Vagrant files. So why is it still looking for VMWare?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by removing the VMWare Fusion plugin:

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vmware-fusion
```

I am not sure why the plugin remained after I completely removed Vagrant, but it works.

Comment: In addition the [basic usage](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/basic_usage.html) help mentions: `vagrant up --provider=virtualbox` and how it chooses a default provider.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the --provider=virtualbox option did not work as long as I had the vagrant-vmware-workstation plugin installed.  Uninstalling the plugin did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do both uninstalls:

vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vmware-fusion
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vmware-desktop

Re-installing vagrant didn't work which make believe that at least on MacOS the uninstaller script is flawed.